# Idiomatic way to create a basic HTTP Post request with Akka HTTP

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I'm trying to figure out how to create a basic HTTP POST request with the Akka HTTP library. This is what I came up with:

```
val formData = Await.result(Marshal(FormData(combinedParams)).to[RequestEntity], Duration.Inf)
val r = HttpRequest(POST, url, headers, formData)
```

The thing is that it seems a bit non-idiomatic to me. Are there other ways to create a HttpEntity from FormData? Especially the fact that I have to use `Await` or return a Future even though the data is readily available seems overly complex for such a simple task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently a `toEntity` method was added to the FormData class at some point. So this now seems like the simplest solution to the problem:

```
val formData = FormData(combinedParams).toEntity
val r = HttpRequest(POST, url, headers, formData)
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use `Marshal` in a for comprehension with other Futures, such as the ones you need to send the request and unmarshall the response:

```
val content = for {
        request <- Marshal(formData).to[RequestEntity]
        response <- Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(method = HttpMethods.POST, uri = s"http://example.com/test", entity = request))
        entity <- Unmarshal(response.entity).to[String]
      } yield entity
```

Comment: might be nice to show the variant of building this as a Future

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `RequestBuilding`:

```js
Http().singleRequest(RequestBuilding.Post(url, formData)).flatMap(Unmarshal(_).to[String])
```

Comment: Recently I've been noticing various [blogs for microservices in akka http](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/spray-the-getting-started/content/spray-akka_http_client.html) that are using `RequestBuilding` but can't find official akka docs on why. Do you know the benefits to using `RequestBuilding`?

Comment: I use it only because it is a shorter form. But yes, I didn't also find any examples in the official docs - that's weird but it works...